# Назначение событий в javascript

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток! Перебираю элементы по тагу у одного родителя и назначаю на них события в цикле, в фаерфоксе все работает, но ишак сопротивляется. Встречался ли кто-нибудь с этим? Может есть какие-то идеи?

Comment: код в студию!

Comment: есть возможность добавить код как код? ато не читаемо получается((

Comment: насколько я понимаю есть кнопочка ( что то наподобии "0101010001" )

Comment: дело в том, что до нормализации события и не доходит. т.е. если сразу воткнуть алерт он не сработает...

Comment: вместо e = e ? e : window.event;

e = e || window.event

это поможет

Comment: сори, что то я никак проснуться не могу.. скорее всего тут дело в том что событиe onclick для option  в IE работают несколько не так. есть смысл смотреть в сторону onchange

Comment: хм... ие, ие... спасибо! буду пробовать!

Answer (score 1):

```
//назначение событий на элементы списка

function select(){
  var list = new Array();
 //обход всех элементов списка
 //назначение события на двойной щелчек
  list = tag('option','p_search_list');  
  for(i in list){
       **list[i].ondblclick = function(){**  //проблема в этом месте
           //ишак тут не назначает событие           
           //вызов функции 
           somefunc(this.value); 
        }; 
     } 
};
```

Comment: можно просто использовать псевдо ссылку для получения значения элемента

Comment: list[i].ondblclick = function(){alert('error');};
ничего не выведет

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="p_search_list">
    <li>11111</li>
    <li>22222</li>
    <li>33333</li>
    <li>44444</li>
    <li>55555</li>
</ul>

<script>
function tag(t,p){
    return document.getElementById(p).getElementsByTagName(t);
}
function select(){
    var list = new Array();
    //обход всех элементов списка
    //назначение события на двойной щелчек
    list = tag('li','p_search_list');  
    for(i in list){
        list[i].ondblclick = function(){  //проблема в этом месте
        //ишак тут не назначает событие           
        //вызов функции 
            alert(this.innerHTML); 
        }; 
    } 
};
select();
</script>
```

Вот это работает, хотя и смотрится странно из-за перебора элементов через for-in. В чем могла быть проблема: вы либо вешаете двойной клик на тег option (мешает стандартное поведение select'а), либо выводите this.value вместо this.innerHTML.

Comment: проблема была со стандартным поведением тега option  в IE, в остальных браузерах все работало. ondblclick сменился на onchange и все заработало)) правда, функция вызывается при первом клике... 
спасибо за участие))